# Is it possible to close </ul> and add new <ul> in the loop?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I am display data from the database. Currently, I have 6 records in my database and I am getting my output like

```
<ul>
<li>Records1</li>
<li>Records2</li>
<li>Records3</li>
<li>Records4</li>
<li>Records5</li>
<li>Records6</li>
</ul>
```

Now what I am doing is, I have to close the `</ul>` tag after 4th `li` tag and then start new `ul` after 4th `li`.

My expected output is

```
<ul>
<li>Records1</li>
<li>Records2</li>
<li>Records3</li>
<li>Records4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Records5</li>
<li>Records6</li>
</ul>
```

is it possible?

I am using below code

```
<?php 
    if ($tyler_query->have_posts()) {
                $index = 0;
                $check=0;
                $first4=0;

      while ( $tyler_query->have_posts() ) {
              $tyler_query->the_post();

           if ($index < 4) {
                     if ($first4==0){?>
<ul>
  <?php $first4=1;}?>
  <li>
    <!--output here-->
  </li>
  <?php  if ($first4==4){?>
</ul>
<?php }?>

<?php } 
            else {
                if ($check==0){?>
<ul>
  <?php $check=1;}?>
  <li>
    <!--output here-->
  </li>
  <?php  }  $index++;}?>
</ul>

<?php   }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert a closing tag followed by an opening tag, whenever it meets your condition.  In the following after every third item:

```
<?php

$items = [
    'Syd',
    'Roger',
    'Nick',
    'David',
    'Richard'
];

$i = 0;
echo '<ul>';
foreach($items as $item) {
    if($i++%3 == 0)
        echo '</ul><ul>';
    echo '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Output:

```
<ul><li>Syd</li><li>Roger</li><li>Nick</li></ul><ul><li>David</li><li>Richard</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quick example. Hope help you.

```
if ($tyler_query->have_posts()) {

    $index = 0;
    $check = 6;
    ?>

    <ul>
    <?php while ($tyler_query->have_posts()) {

        $tyler_query->the_post(); ?>

        <li><?php echo 'some_value' ?></li>

        <?php if ($index % $check === 0 ) { ?>

        </ul><ul>

        <?php }

        $index++;
    } ?>
    </ul>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

your code would work if you echo the HTML tag/output you want to see in the browser.

```
<?php
if ($tyler_query->have_posts()) {
    $index = 0;
    $check = 0;
    $first4 = 0;

    while ($tyler_query->have_posts()) {

        $tyler_query->the_post();
        $output = "whatever the output object is";

        if ($index < 4) {
            if ($first4 == 0) {
                echo '<ul>';
                $first4 = 1; // increment so that the this if block wont trigger again
            }
            echo '<li>' . $output . '</li>';
            // increment so that the next if block trigger once
            if ($first4 == 4) {
                echo  '</ul>';
            }
            $first4++;
        }
        if ($index >= 4){
            if ($check == 0) {
                echo '<ul>';
                $check = 1;
            }
            // assuming you want to have the rest of the data in this block.
            // data 5 and above
            else {
                echo '<li>' . $output . '</li>';
            }
        }
            $index++;
        }
    echo '</ul>';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: How the echo will work in your answer? closing PHP before echo

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't read the question much carefully and make a lot of assumptions, and now that I had read the questions again I see that you use multiple "php tag" block and im confused why though. ive re-done it so it should work now

Comment: Let me check your answer. Give me some time

Comment: I haven't understood this line         $output = "whatever the output object is"; Should I add my li tag code here

Comment: this variable can be an object that you created base from the database row you are fetching or just the string you want to output (ex. name, email, and etc)

Comment: I am getting output <ul></ul><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><ul></ul><li></li><li></li>

Comment: my bad, there was a logical error when I did this should work now

Comment: Yes, this time getting correct output but I have 6 records but  I am getting only 5

Comment: I added 10 records and  it still showing 9 records,